# Sorting setof records returned by a function

Tags: postgresql

I wrote a function to return a set of records (RETURNS SETOF) , using return next.

Is there a way  to sort the result set before returning? something like accessing a reference of the set, sort it, then return. 
I already did use order by in some queries, but i need to write additional code to sort the result.

As a workaround i'm calling the function like this:

```
select * from (select * from myfunction() ) d 
order by d.whatever,d.othercolumn
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to order data before return next - you can wrap call of your function in another function, select data from it with desired ordering and return it.

Comment: Thanks, i think i'll do that.

Comment: Note: if you use the function's resultset in a join with another "real" table, the order can not be "seen" by the query optimiser (it cannot look "inside" the function), so the join will involve either an explicit sort step+merge, or a hash lookup.